# ldap injection in c++

Tags: c++, ldap

I'm trying to find all the possible ways to do LDAP injection in C++.
Till now I found only one function `ldap_search_ext_s`.
Maybe I don't understand the vulnerability and this is why I can't find more :/

Thanks.

Comment: This question seems to lack a question. Are you asking how to defend against it, perform it, or something else?

Comment: I'm asking how can I perform it, or in more detail witch LDAP function are vulnerable for injection. @zenzelezz